# How do I setup zipkin to trace different applications running on activemq?

Tags: activemq-classic, zipkin

The infrastructure of system used by my company consists of different application running on a `ActiveMQ`. I want to know how would I setup `Zipkin` to trace the communication between different applications under `ActiveMQ`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about ActiveMQ but you need to pass the zipkin trace information along.

Review the *ActiveMQ Collector* section in this doc 
https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/zipkin-server/README.md

I just set up Zipkin tracing for a stack that includes RabbitMQ. I added the parent_span_id, and span_id to the message header before the message is placed on the queue. Then the applications that read the messages get the trace information from the header.

And if you need more help, I recommend jumping on IRC #zipkin.